# UV Editor view and viewport display not matching

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

EDIT: linked the  blender file [image]

I'm having issues mapping out some textures onto an object. For some reasons that I can't figure out, my face mapping doesn't match the way the textures are displayed in the Viewport

Here's what my mapping looks like in the UV Editor

[image: Here's how my faces are setup in the UV Editor]

[image]

And here's what I get in the Viewport.
Does someone have some insights on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see you Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add the link to your question. You'll need to pack the textures into the blend file first though via File > External Data > Pack Resources before saving it.

Comment: Even if you're not uploading the file could you at least show the material's node setup in the _Shader Editor_? The best UV unwrapping is useless if the texture does not use the UV map, for example because you have a _Texture Coordinate_ node in there and use the _Generated_ output or something else.

Comment: Here's a link to a copy of the blender file incriminated : https://blend-exchange.com/b/zp18y9As

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've edited the *Mapping* rotation and scale values, it affects the way the texture will be displayed, reset these values (right click > *Reset All to Default Values*):

[image]